# How to avoid Grails automatically rebuilding my project on every change?

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, build, rebuild

I have an old Grails 1.1.1 project that I had to upgrade to version 1.3.5 with STS Pro.

As expected, some debris is floating around that may be causing issues, but I'm not sure that's causing the problem.

This is the problem: Every time I save a class (Java or Groovy), it automatically rebuilds the whole project and creates a war file.

Is this the normal behavior? Actually, I don't mind it that much, just because the build runs on the background. The problem is that the build sometimes locks some resources temporarily, and I am having an annoying popup that says that it could not deploy because an assertion failed.

By the way, it doesn't say what was the assertion, so I have to click "OK" every time.

This is becoming a real pain.

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew is probably right. I created a new Grails project from scratch, and executed the project using the command grails dev run-app (which can be run from STS).

I had no problems, and it behaved as expected: I was able to hot-deploy changes to my code, without regenerating and deploying a WAR file. Unfortunately, the console in STS does not show when it has finished compiling and the web-app is ready, so I have to wait a little bit before refreshing my browser.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reference documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html), you could do:

```
grails -Ddisable.auto.recompile=true run-app
```

However, you'll have to restart the application every time you make a change.

Comment: After re-reading your question, this may not be the ideal solution, since in your situation it's not just recompiling, it's building a war. But I'm curious whether or not it works.

Comment: Rob. Please see my answer below. In the end, it was worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the new feature (new to 2.5.1) to deploy your grails app to tc server, rather than calling grails run-app.

This is a new feature that we have just added and so it is still rough around the edges and may be rebuilding the war file when it is not entirely necessary.  I'd recommend that you raise a jira issue for this:
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue calling grails run-app.  STS is triggering the WAR build each time, so although I can access my changes instantly in the browser, STS starts chewing CPU cycles & pausing while it rebuilds.
I can't help saving often.  I grew up playing space quest so it's been habit for a long long time.

Comment: I'm with you. Please take a look to my own answer above. Be sure to have the latest release, and follow the instructions above. It worked for me, and I hope it works for you. Luis